# Google Sheets: Conditional Formatting IF cell is a duplicate AND is not empty

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with website URLs. I'd like to highlight them in red if they are a duplicate AND are not empty.

Here's my current approach, applied to the column range:

```
=AND(countif(E:E,E1)>1,not(ISBLANK(E:E)))
```

The countif part will find duplicates. But I'm not sure what should be going in between in `ISBLANK()` part. How do I refer to "this" cell?

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=And((countif(E:E,E1)>1),not(isBlank(E1)))
```

refer to the cell as E1 like you do in countif.

Another way to refer to current cell is like this:

```
=INDIRECT(address(row(),column())
```

So you can modify the above condition to this:

```
=And((countif(E:E,INDIRECT(address(row(),column())))>1),not(isBlank(INDIRECT(address(row(),column())))))
```